# ffmpeg yuvj422p color movie conversion avi2ogv

Tags: ffmpeg, yuv, avi, file-conversion

While converting avi video to ogv, there is a color problem in output file.
How can I solve this issue ?
[normal colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXKO1.png) [altered colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImmgO.png)

**Actually a part of the problem is from the player - so weak question**

Command using ffmpeg-3.3.2-1.mga6.tainted :

```
ffmpeg -i dscn0146.avi -pix_fmt yuv422p -s 640x480 dscn0146_hq.ogv -y
```

And input metadata:

```
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, avi, from 'dscn0146.avi':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : 
    maker           : NIKON
    model           : COOLPIX S3500
    creation_time   : 2017-07-22 12:09:06
  Duration: 00:00:07.33, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11091 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480, 10770 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, mono, s16, 352 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> theora (libtheora))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le (native) -> vorbis (libvorbis))
```

Processes normaly, but fires a warning:

```
[swscaler @ 0xd3c3a0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
```

Output metadata:

```
Output #0, ogv, to 'dscn0146_hq.ogv':
  Metadata:
    model           : COOLPIX S3500
    maker           : NIKON
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: theora (libtheora), yuv422p(progressive), 640x480, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libtheora
      model           : COOLPIX S3500
      maker           : NIKON
    Stream #0:1: Audio: vorbis (libvorbis), 22050 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.89.100 libvorbis
      model           : COOLPIX S3500
      maker           : NIKON
```

Comment: How are you playing the output? Can you share the input? First guess: your player only decodes 4:2:0 but doesn't catch if source format is different.

Comment: Indeed my vlc player does not decode completely (vlc-3.0.0-0.git.19.mga6.tainted.x86_64). Dragon Player does (dragon-16.12.3-1.mga6). So I wonder what is the best way to convert and test...

Answer (score 0):

this working code

```
ffmpeg -i totoa.avi -c:v libtheora -q:v 10 -c:a libvorbis -q:a 5 -s 640x480 -y toto.ogv
```

Comment: your syntax is complete, but does not solve my problem (which involves the video player). Sorry my question is weak.